# How to join two files with matching IDs in linux

Tags: linux, shell, file, unix, join

I have the first file

```
112 apple
113 tomato
114 pasta 
115 beaf
```

The second file is

```
112 4
113 6
114 8
```

I want to get

```
112 4 apple
113 6 tomato
114 8 pasta
```

I've tried the following code in linux without success:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=$2; next} seen[$NF]{print $0, seen[$NF]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Look into the `join` command

Comment: Change your command to `awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=$2; next}  ($1 in seen){print $0, seen[$1]}' file2 file1` and it should fly then.

Comment: Good (first?) question! Inputs, outpus, code. Excellent. But see if your system as `apropos` and run commands like `apropos join`. You may find there is a utility already available (-) (as mentioned above). Good luck and keep posting!